# Linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

Tags: substrate-node-template, orml

I want to use orml-traits in substrate project. I'm using this [substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate)

and also I cloned this repo for using `orml` project in local:[orml Repository](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library)

I changed some crates in `orml-traits` `Cargo.toml` :

I added these files into the `orml-traits Cargo.toml` instead of previous:

```
    frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../frame/support" }
frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../frame/system" }
sp-io = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, path = "../../primitives/io" }
sp-runtime = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, path = "../primitives//runtime" }
sp-std = { version = "5.0.0", default-features = false, path = "../primitives/std" }
```

and use the `orml-traits` in pallet:

```
orml-traits = { path="../../../orlem/traits", default-features = false, version = "0.4.1-dev" }
```

When I run `cargo check` everything is ok and it doesn't show me any errors, but when I run `cargo build --release` it show me this error:

```
 = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `wasm_to_host_trampoline':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.15:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `wasm_to_host_trampoline'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.4.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.4:(.text+0x0): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.15.rcgu.o): in function `host_to_wasm_trampoline':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.15:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `host_to_wasm_trampoline'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.4.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.4:(.text+0x20): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.2.rcgu.o): in function `resolve_vmctx_memory':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.2:(.text.resolve_vmctx_memory+0x0): multiple definition of `resolve_vmctx_memory'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.12.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.12:(.text.resolve_vmctx_memory+0x0): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.2.rcgu.o): in function `resolve_vmctx_memory_ptr':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.2:(.text.resolve_vmctx_memory_ptr+0x0): multiple definition of `resolve_vmctx_memory_ptr'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.12.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.12:(.text.resolve_vmctx_memory_ptr+0x0): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.2.rcgu.o): in function `set_vmctx_memory':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.2:(.text.set_vmctx_memory+0x0): multiple definition of `set_vmctx_memory'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.12.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.12:(.text.set_vmctx_memory+0x0): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4.rcgu.o): in function `memory32_grow':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `memory32_grow'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11:(.text+0x0): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4.rcgu.o): in function `table_copy':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `table_copy'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11:(.text+0x20): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4.rcgu.o): in function `table_init':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of `table_init'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11:(.text+0x40): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4.rcgu.o): in function `elem_drop':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `elem_drop'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11.rcgu.o):wasmtime_runtime.eba4c0e3-cgu.11:(.text+0x60): first defined here
      /usr/bin/ld: /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-78ebbc493a85468a.wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4.rcgu.o): in function `memory_copy':
      wasmtime_runtime.e9463095-cgu.4:(.text+0x80): multiple definition of `memory_copy'; /home/kianoush/projects/music-chain/target/release/deps/libwasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.rlib(wasmtime_runtime-869794614aaf5f6d.wasmtime_runtime.eb



error: could not compile `node-cli` due to previous error
```

Comment: did it build successfully after you cloned those repositoeies and before you made any code changes? do you have enough memory and hard disk space, see https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7549/83

Comment: @LukeSchoen , yes , it did success build before i change any thing .